# save file from array using fs without seperator

Tags: node.js, fs

I have problem to save array to file, I don't now way I always getting ',' separator in new file that I assuming means new row in array. So for example I have file

```
this is file
with text
to check
```

I read this file save to array make some modification and then I want to save this file.

```
 fs.writeFile('to_save', file.map(function(x){return x + '\n'}));
```

When I do like that I always getting new file with ,

```
,this is file
,with text
,to check
```

when I try to remove firs letter using

```
fs.writeFile('to_save', file.map(function(x){return x = x.substring(1, x.length) + '\n'}));
```

It remove me t, w and t, so my question is how to get ride this separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use join instead of map

```
fs.writeFile('to_save', file.join("\n"));
```

[`writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) expects a string, a buffer, or an Uint8Array as data. It will implicitly call `toString()` on an array, which is why you'll get the commas.

Comment: so why join is working, if still writeFile will call toString() ?

Comment: It will implicitly call toString() on an **array**, `join` returns a string

Comment: For the record this also worked for my appendFile needs:
`fs.appendFile('file_name.txt', data.join("\n"), function (err) {}...`